# Disable button from inverted bool

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to disable a button if this property is false:

```
public bool HasRightSELECT { get; set; }
```

I tried to achieve thsi with:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" disabled="!@Model.TablesWithRights[i].HasRightSELECT" name="View" value="@i">View</button>
```

or

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" disabled="@{!Model.TablesWithRights[i].HasRightSELECT}" name="Insert" value="@i">Insert</button>
```

I know I could just rename the property to `HasNORightSelect` but I am wondering how I can set the disable value with the "inverted" value.

Comment: I can accept answeres in two minutes and solved it a little bit different. I kind of feel bad for @AlexB if i would answere my own question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `disabled` is present, no matter the value, your button will be disabled.

You shoud try something like :

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" @(!Model.TablesWithRights[i].HasRightSELECT ? "disabled" : "") name="View" value="@i">
    View
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add an `if` statement:

```
@if(Model.TablesWithRights[i].HasRightSELECT)
{
     <input disabled/>    
}
else
{
     <input/>
}
```

BTW [`disabled` is a property (not an attribute)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003819/what-is-the-difference-between-properties-and-attributes-in-html) so shouldn't contain a value. It's presence designates if something is disabled or not.

Another (cleaner) option would be to add a computed value to your model:

```
public bool HasRightSELECT { get; set; }
public string HasRightSELECTdisabled
{
   get
   {
       if (this.HasRightSELEC)
           return "disabled";
       else
           return string.Empty;
   }
}

<input @Model.TablesWithRights[i].HasRightSELECTdisabled />
```

Comment: That's open to debate. They both work so choose whichever you prefer